# MapKit Overlays - Circles

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm trying to add a circle overlay to the map but it never happens - the annotations are added but thats it
Here is the code sample

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer 
 let circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
 circle.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
 circle.strokeColor = UIColor.red
 circle.lineWidth = 9
 return circle
}

let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinates, radius: 9000)
 mapView.addAnnotation(Loka_Location)
 mapView.addOverlay(circle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missed setting the delegate of the mapView.

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

and don't forget to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {}
```